# inlcude directive in asciidoc always evaluates relative

Tags: asciidoc

I have an include in one of my asciidoc files

```
include::{sourcedir}/samples/test.java[]
```

sourcedir is set when calling the asciidoc converter and contains an absolute path (starting /Users/User1...). However, asciidoc always puts the whole current path in front of the file when evaluating the expression. This ends up in an error

> SEVERE: test.adoc: line 5: include file not found: /Users/User1/git/repo/workDir/Users/User1...[]test.jav

How can I make sure that asciidoc evaluated that path as an absolute path?

Comment: Which converter are you using? Asciidoctor?

Comment: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-ant